# Facebook Posts Search using Graph API v2.1

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch posts from a particular facebook page using the Facebook Graph API v2.1. Below is the URL which I tried:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/search?access_token=xxxxxxxx&q=hello&type=post&fields=from,message,name,caption,description,created_time&limit=2
```

But I am getting below error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 11
   }
}
```

I tried with older versions as well but I am getting the same error message.

I am using app access token to fetch the same.

Is there no way to fetch public posts / comments from a facebook page using Facebook Graph Rest API.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public Post search was deprecated with Graph API v2.0, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

If your app isn't a v1.0 app (created before April 30th 2014), then you have no chance to use the public Post search. Even if it is, it will stop working on April 30th 2015. You'd have to prefix your request with `/v1.0` like the following:

```
/v1.0/search?type=post&q=foobar
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi. So it means that facebook4j or any other Facebook Graph API client will also not provide posts after April 30th 2015?

Comment: For sure not, they are just wrappers around the Graph API. And, as I said, you can only currently use the public post search if you have a v1.0 app.

Comment: so now we only can get the posts using User access token for an authenicated user.